# Tengo problemas con la calculadora que estoy haciendo

Tags: python-3.x

este es el código que tengo no obtengo el resultado, según lo eh revisado 100 veces esta bien, si alguien me puede ayudar seria de mucha ayuda,
Tambien por favor si no seria mucha molestia.Al intentar hacer una publicación por que me dice que estoy poniendo puro codigo en la publicacion si es una pagina que a mi parecer es para esto.

```
import tkinter as tk
raiz=tk.Tk()
raiz.title("Calculadora")
miframe=tk.Frame(raiz)
miframe.pack()

def evaluar(valor):
    if valor=="sumar":
            valor1=int(n1.get())
            valor2=int(n2.get())
            respuesta.set(valor1 + valor2)
    if valor=="restar":        
            valor1=int(n1.get())
            valor2=int(n2.get())
            respuesta.set(valor1 + valor2)

n1=tk.StringVar()
n2=tk.StringVar()
respuesta=tk.StringVar()

labelnumero1=tk.Label(miframe, text="Numero 1")
labelnumero1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

cuadronumero1=tk.Entry(miframe, textvariable=n1)
cuadronumero1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

labelnumero2=tk.Label(miframe, text="Numero 2")
labelnumero2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

cuadronumero2=tk.Entry(miframe, textvariable=n2)
cuadronumero2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

labelrespuesta=tk.Label(miframe, text="Respuesta")
labelrespuesta.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

casillarespuesta=tk.Entry(miframe, textvariable=respuesta)
casillarespuesta.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

buttonsuma=tk.Button(miframe, text="sumar", command = evaluar("sumar"))
buttonsuma.grid(row=0, column=2)

buttonresta=tk.Button(miframe, text="Restar", command = evaluar("restar"))
buttonresta.grid(row=1, column=2)

buttonmultiplicar=tk.Button(miframe, text="Multiplicar")
buttonmultiplicar.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

buttondividir=tk.Button(miframe, text="Dividir")
buttondividir.grid(row=1, column=3)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pide algo más que código porque la idea es explicar para qué es, cuál es la pregunta, qué se espera que el código haga, qué está haciendo en su lugar, con qué datos se prueba, cuál es la salida esperada, etc. Ánimo, no desesperes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes un par de errores en el programa. Uno es un despiste tonto, muy fácil de arreglar, y es que la función `evaluar()`, para el caso `"restar"` está haciendo también la suma :-)

Ya de paso podemos arreglar un poco más esta función y sacar fuera de los condicionales la parte común (la toma de los datos):

```
def evaluar(valor):
    valor1=int(n1.get())
    valor2=int(n2.get())
    if valor=="sumar":
        respuesta.set(valor1 + valor2)
    elif valor=="restar":
        respuesta.set(valor1 - valor2)
```

El otro fallo es más complicado de explicar y de resolver. Así que hago una sección para ello.

## El parámetro `command` de los botones

Mediante `tk.Button()` creas un botón y en el momento de crearlo debes asociarle un texto a mostrar en él y una función *a ejecutar cuando el botón se pulse*. Para ello tienes que pasarle a `command` una variable o símbolo que represente una función.

En tu caso en cambio le pasas algo como `evaluar("sumar")`. Eso causa que Python ejecute esa función *en el momento que se crea el botón* (y no cuando se pulse), para hallar cuál es el valor devuelto por `evaluar("sumar")` y es **ese valor devuelto** el que se asigna como comando para el botón.

En tu caso, esa función no tiene ninguna sentencia `return`, por lo que implícitamente retorna `None`. De modo que el comando que se asocia con el botón es `None`. Cuando se pulse el botón, se intentará ejecutar `None`, el cual no es ejecutable, y el programa romperá. Eso si no fuera porque ya rompió antes, al intentar ejecutar `evaluar("sumar")` pues en ese momento en que la ejecutas se intenta acceder a los valores de los inputs, los cuales aún están vacíos, y falla la conversión a `int`.

En resumen el problema está en que **ejecutas `evaluar()`** demasiado pronto, y no cuando se pulsa el botón.

## La solución típica (que no sirve en tu caso)

Lo habitual es asignar a `command` el nombre de una función, y no el resultado de llamarla. Es decir, algo como `command=funcion_a_ejecutar`. Cuando el botón se pulse, será el propio botón el que invocará `funcion_a_ejecutar()`, pero nunca le pasará ningún parámetro. Por tanto si hicierámos `command=evaluar`, cuando se pulsara el botón éste llamaría a `evaluar()`, pero sin pasarle parámetros.

En tu caso esto es un problema porque necesitas que a `evaluar()` se le pase un parámetro, según la operación a realizar. Pero no puedes poner ese parámetro en la asignación a `command`, pues eso ejecutaría la función en ese momento. Ni puedes esperar a que el botón se lo pase cuando sea pulsado, pues los botones no están preparados para pasar parámetro alguno a su `command`.

## Soluciones para tu caso

Tienes dos soluciones. Una sencilla pero un tanto fea, pues repite código. Otra más elegante, pero más avanzada pues usa conceptos de programación funcional (*aplicaciones parciales*).

#### Solución sencilla repitiendo código

Ya que la función a ejecutar cuando se pulsa el botón no puede recibir parámetros, puedes escribir diferentes funciones según la operación a realizar. Por ejemplo:

```
def evalua_suma():
    valor1=int(n1.get())
    valor2=int(n2.get())
    respuesta.set(valor1 + valor2)

def evalua_resta():
    valor1=int(n1.get())
    valor2=int(n2.get())
    respuesta.set(valor1 - valor2)
```

y así con todas las demás. Entonces asignarás estas funciones a los comandos de los respectivos botones:

```
buttonsuma=tk.Button(miframe, text="sumar", command = evalua_suma)
buttonresta=tk.Button(miframe, text="Restar", command = evalua_resta)
```

El inconveniente de esta solución es la **repetición de código**, pues las funciones en cuestión son todas muy similares, con código repetido.

#### Solución avanzada usando aplicaciones parciales

Python, en su módulo `functools` proporciona una función llamada `partial()`, que recibe como parámetros otra función `f`, y cualquier otra cosa `x`. Por ejemplo: `g = partial(f, x)`. Te retorna como resultado una nueva función `g` que ya se puede invocar sin parámetros. Cuando invoques `g()`, ésta internamente hará `f(x)`.

> **Nota** en realidad es algo más complejo, pues puede que `f` recibiera varios parámetros, y en ese caso `g(mas)` llamaría a `f(x, mas)`. Y también puedes hacer *aplicación parcial* de varios parámeros, en vez de uno solo. Pero podemos quedarnos con la explicación simplificada para este caso.

Es decir, si nos quedamos con tu versión original de `evalua`, o incluso una en la que se repite aún menos código:

```
def evaluar(valor):
    valor1=int(n1.get())
    valor2=int(n2.get())
    if valor=="sumar":
        r = valor1 + valor2
    elif valor=="restar":
        r = valor1 - valor2
    elif valor == "multiplicar":
        r = valor1 * valor2
    # elif.... etc....

    respuesta.set(r)
```

Haciendo uso de `partial()` puedes hacer `g = partial(evaluar, "sumar")` y cuando llames a `g()` es como si hubieras llamado a `evaluar("sumar")`, por tanto esta `g` podría ser el `command` de un botón.

En definitiva, que puedes programar los botones de esta otra forma:

```
from functools import partial

buttonsuma=tk.Button(miframe, text="sumar", command = partial(evaluar, "sumar"))
buttonresta=tk.Button(miframe, text="Restar", command = partial(evaluar, "restar"))
```

Es importante que entiendas que `partial(evaluar, "sumar")` no está invocando en ese momento a `evaluar`, sino creando una nueva función (que es la que se asocia al botón), que cuando sea ejecutada (al pusar el botón) **sí** ejecutará `evaluar("sumar")`. Y así con el resto de botones.

Comment: Muchas gracias por explicarme lo del botón la verdad no tome en cuenta que no podría recibir parámetros predefinidos desde el botón, eso explica muchas dudas por que cuando corría el programa se dirigía a la función.
Aplicando lo que me mostraste tengo un inconveniente con la importación hace referencia a que no encuentra el lugar donde se encuentra "partial"

Comment: Si, había un error. Era functools en vez de itertools. ya lo he arreglado

Comment: Genial y otra vez muchas gracias por tu ayuda